# How to open a modal after waiting for the state to set in React native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, use-state

I have a screen with some choices on. If you select the choice it sets state of the data. I then have a confirm button. if the user hits confirm I make an async call to get some extra data. I want to wait for this to happen before opening the modal as I need to present that extra data in my modal.

before hooks I would use setState and do something like:
`this.setState({data: myData}, () => this.openModal())` as this would reliably set the state then open the modal. all the answers online seem to suggest using `useEffect` but it seems dodgy to do this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
        setModalOpen(true)
    }
}, [data, setData])
```

I don't want my modal potentially randomly opening at different points. plus it seems better to have the code living in the same place I set state. it makes sense to be there. not some random `useEffect`

any suggestions how this can be achieved?

(one other solution I can think of is making the API call on every choice select, rather than before confirm) however, this could lead to a lot of unnecessary API calls so I'd rather not go down that route.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're simply not calling `setModalOpen(true)` after the async call? Relying on data being set as a medium for displaying a modal might result to unexpected situations. If you're using `redux-thunk`, then you can simply await for the dispatch to finish, set the data and then set the modal visibility.

Comment: nope.. this worked. for some reason I just assumed it wouldn't? because I'm setting the state of the async call after. then opening the modal after. assumed there might be a chance of it not being synchronous, but maybe not?

Comment: As long as the dispatched thunk or async operation is awaited, then setting the state of both the data and visibility should happen synchrnously.

Comment: Did my answer help you somehow? Please consider giving some feedback, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using `useEffect()` is correct, I also encountered this issue when trying to do a callback on setState with hooks.

Like you said: `this.setState({data: myData}, () => this.openModal())` was possible before, but now when trying this with hooks the console displays the error:

> Warning: State updates from the useState() and useReducer() Hooks don't support the second callback argument. To execute a side effect after rendering, declare it in the component body with useEffect().

So `useEffect()` seems the way to go.

You should use `useEffect()` as a callback after the state is correctly setted if you would like to do something with the state like validation.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // fetch on load
  axios.get("https://randomuser.me/api/").then((response) => {
    setPerson(response.data.results[0]);
  });
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  // do some validation perhaps
  if (person !== null) {
    if (person.name.first && person.name.last) {
      setModal(true);
    } else {
      setModal(false);
    }
  }
}, [person]); // add person in dependency list
```

As suggested in the comments, you could also do `setModal()` when the async data has arrived (using `.then() or await`).

Some example code using *random user generator API* and *axios* for fetching.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    // fetch on load
    axios.get("https://randomuser.me/api/").then((response) => {
      setPerson(response.data.results[0]);
      setModal(true); // set modal visibility
    });
  }, []);
```